# How can I get my controller by HttpContextBase?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, httpcontext

I have base controller, assume that, it has a property named `AnyProperty`:

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
    {
        public MyObject AnyProperty { get; set; }

        public MyBaseController()
        {
            AnyProperty = new MyObject();
        }
    }
```

In `RoleAttribute` I need to use `AnyProperty`. I use

```
public class RoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            MyBaseController controllerInstance = new MyBaseController();
            controllerInstance.AnyProperty   // I use like this 
        }
    }
```

How can I get my `AnyProperty` property by  `httpContext`? 
not using `MyBaseController` instance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is in another method, but it might be helpful:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as MyBaseController;
    if (controller == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    controller.AnyProperty = new MyObject();
}
```